# Replacing substring in every file in every directory and subdirectory

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace, python-2to3

I have a framework that is using Python 2.7 and I am currently converting it to python 3. However, there are many files that direct to "C:\Python27... etc" to grab certain scripts. I want to go through every file in every framework directory and subdirectory, and change this substring in the file, "..\Python27..", into Python38.
For instance, I have this in a .bat file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
if not exist .\env27 (
  if not exist C:\Python27\Scripts\virtualenv.exe (
    echo VirtualEnv not found: C:\Python27\Scripts >&2
    exit /b 1
  )
  C:\Python27\Scripts\virtualenv .\env27
 ....
```

I would want to replace C:\Python27\Scripts\virtualenv.exe into
C:\Python38\Scripts\virtualenv.exe

I have tried this code [Python - Way to recursively find and replace string in text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205854/python-way-to-recursively-find-and-replace-string-in-text-files), but it works for an exact string and not a substring. This is my code so far:

```
import os, fnmatch

def findAndReplace(directory, find, replacement):
    for dname, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for fname in files:
            fpath = os.path.join(dname, fname)
            with open(fpath) as f:
                s = f.read()
            s = s.replace(find, replacement)
            with open(fpath, "w") as f:
                f.write(s)
```

I am wondering how I can replace substrings?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give an example of substrings you'd like to replace?

Comment: I just added an example ^ to my question. Thanks!

Comment: What did you try as `find` and `replacement`? `s.replace(r"\Python27", r"\Python38")` did not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` to search for the text groups you needed. I encourage you to check out the [regex documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for specifics on how to make the patterns needed. If finding specific substrings fitting a pattern was not the issue, please clarify, because that's what I'm getting from this.

```
import os, re

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('path to directory'):
  for infile in files:
    with open(os.path.join(root, infile)) as in_text:
      contents = in_text.read()
    with open(os.path.join(root, infile), 'w') as out:
      out.write(re.sub(find, replacement, contents))
```

If there's more specifics to this that I haven't covered, I'm sorry. Just let me know if that's the case, and I'll do my best to address it!